# Sitecore 7.1 MVC Html.Sitecore().Field not giving same result as FieldRenderer.Render

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.1

I have a Sitecore 7.1 solution using MVC and am rendering fields using `@Html.Sitecore().Field("FieldName", ContentItem)`.  Because I want multiline text fields to render out `<br/>` tags I have removed the `GetTextFieldValue` processor from the renderField processor section in `web.config` using an `App_Config\Include` patch file as described here: http://laubplusco.net/sitecore-update-bummer/.  What I'm finding is that if I use `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.Render()` this produces the output with the line breaks as expected, but if I use the `Html.Sitecore().Field()` extension method no line break is rendered.

I found that you can write

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("FieldName", item, new { linebreaks = "<br/>" })
```

which seems to do the job.

**Is there some other config which needs to be set to make the `Field()` extension method behave in the same way as `FieldRenderer.Render`, or do I just have to use the method above?**

Comment: Try this solution here, it could help
http://www.letsdositecore.com/enabling-html-tags-in-single-line-text-fields/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of field rendering seems to be different for MVC and WebForms. You can check the code of `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.RenderField()` in .NET Reflector. It adds line breaks for multi-line fields to the `RenderFieldArgs`, before calling the render field pipeline:

```
        if (item.Fields[this.FieldName].TypeKey == "multi-line text")
        {
            args.RenderParameters["linebreaks"] = "<br/>";
        }
```

In @Html.Sitecore().Field(...) the rendering pipeline is called in a similar way, but the rendering arguments are set up differently, "linebreaks" is not added. To make the behavior the same for every rendering you could add your own processor with the same logic as the code above in `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer.RenderField()`. Somehow like this:

```
public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");

    if (args.FieldTypeKey == "multi-line text")
        args.RenderParameters["linebreaks"] = "<br/>";
}
```

and add this to your render field pipeline with an include file.